# Get only last 10 datas from database but print the array the other way around

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm working with a Chart, I need to get the last 10 datas from my database and print it into my Chart. Well, I could easily do that, but the problem is, the data is being printed the other way around, so instead of being printed like, this is only example: 1 2 3 4 5, it is being printed 5 4 3 2 1. I need it to print the normal way. 
This is my code:

```
  $id = $_SESSION['userId']; 
  $dBname = "infosensor";
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBname);

  $sql = "SELECT sensor1, sensor2, sensor3, dias FROM `$id` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10;";

  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $jsonsensor1 = array();
  $jsonsensor2 = array();
  $jsonsensor3 = array();
  $jsonsensorsum = array();
  $date = array();
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
  {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
      $jsonsensor1[] = intval($row['sensor1'] * ($p = pow(10, 2))) / $p;
      $jsonsensor2[] = intval($row['sensor2'] * ($p = pow(10, 2))) / $p;
      $jsonsensor3[] = intval($row['sensor3'] * ($p = pow(10, 2))) / $p;
      $jsonsensorsum[] = intval(($row['sensor1'] + $row['sensor2'] + $row['sensor3']) * ($p = pow(10, 2))) / $p;

      //Data
      $geral = (date('d/m/y', strtotime(str_replace('.', '-', $row['dias']))));
      $date[] = $geral;

      //Horario
      $horario = (date('H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('.', '-', $row['dias']))));    
      $tempo[] = explode(',', $horario);
    } 
  }

  $data = [$jsonsensor1,$jsonsensor2,$jsonsensor3,$jsonsensorsum, $date];

  echo json_encode($data);
```

The problem way be here:

```
$sql = "SELECT sensor1, sensor2, sensor3, dias FROM `$id` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10;";
```

Comment: What about just PHP solution of `$data = array_reverse($data);`?

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT sensor1, sensor2, sensor3, dias
FROM (
    SELECT sensor1, sensor2, sensor3, dias, id FROM `$id` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
) t
ORDER BY id
```

Or, if you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT sensor1, sensor2, sensor3, dias
FROM (
    SELECT sensor1, sensor2, sensor3, dias, id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id DESC) rn
    FROM `$id`
) t
WHERE rn <= 10
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Why is there a 't' at the first example? And I should just put it into my variable?

Comment: @Matheus: this is a table alias for the derived table that is generated by the subquery. In MySQL (and many other RDBMS as well), it is mandatory to give aliases to every derived table.

Comment: Ok, Could you guys wrap it up on your answer so it can be clear to use in php?

Comment: @Matheus: well, just `$sql = "<... the above query ...>";`

Comment: Nevermind, the 2 answer you posted didn't work for some reason the 1 query worked/